# Using C++ code on iOS, create a static library or mix with Objective C?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, static-libraries

I have some C++ code (exposing a C-only interface through a header) which I will use for an iOS project.

I can either create a static library and link to this from my app project, or add the source files directly to the app project - which option is best?

All answers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the sources if you expect them to change often. Otherwise a library will be more suitable and will make your project cleaner (however, you will have to put only the header files in your project)

Answer (score 1):

I've used OpenCV in one of my app projects which is mostly written in C++. I've found that adding the source files to the app project worked better for me because I made some minor changes to the code wherever appropriate. Comes down to the use case basically.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to add the source if I have it, simply because it makes debugging easier.  If you're making a call into a library routine and getting back an unexpected result (or crashing, or whatever), it's much easier to step into the library code with the debugger and figure out what's going on.  If you just have a static library, it's a black box and you can't see what's going on inside.  It also allows you to change the library code more easily if you encounter a bug or a missing feature (just be careful if the library is shared among other projects, to make sure you keep the library code up to date in its own repository).

Xcode is good about letting you keep your project organized, so use those features to your advantage.  Keep the library code and headers separate from your main application and link it in as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by code you don't mean a well formed library, so I expect this code could get any kind of modification pressure in the future. The best way is then wrapping it. here is one very nice example, but you might do it differently: http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-cppfinal-edition-759